# Full-Text indexing with SQL Server 2012 without storing the files

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I was wondering, is it possible to use the Full-Text search of SQL Server 2012 without storing the documents in the database? I know that there are several services that offer file indexing without then storing your files, but only the indexed data; is it possible to use SQL Server 2012 that way?

Fabio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As of today, the full-text index is dynamically modified based on the table contents. So if you were to delete the rows holding the data the index will be updated to reflect the changed table.

I am assuming that you have looked at solutions like [Filestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) to store unstructured data on the file system and are instead looking at getting rid of the indexed documents entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm well aware of the Filestreams. I'd like to use SQL Server like Lucene, I guess this isn't possible.